# passing a reference to useState to an object outside the React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mvvm, react-hooks

In an attempt to implement the MVVM pattern in react I've come up with the following solution.

A Viewmodel which calls a notify method whenever it's state has changed.

```
class Viewmodel{
 value:number;
 notify:()=>void;
 constructor(notify:()=>void){
  this.notify = notify;
  this.value = 0;
 }

 update(){
  this.value = this.value + 1;
  this.notify();
 }
}
```

A component which relies on Props. Nothing different here

```
interface MyComponentProps{
 value:number;
}
function MyComponent(props:MyComponentProps):JSX.Element{
 return (<div>{props.value}</div>)
}
```

A component which uses useState to create the viewmodel object, and also uses useState to create the required notify method to be passed to the viewmodel.

```
function MyParentComponent(){
const notify = ()=> setProps({value:vm.value});
const [vm] = useState<Viewmodel>(new Viewmodel(notify));
const [props, setProps] = useState<MyComponentProps>({value:0});
return <MyComponent {...props} />
}
```

When the Viewmodels update method is called, it changes it's internal state then calls notify() which in turn executes useState and updates the Component. This all works the way I wish however I'm left wondering if this can lead to some subtle bugs. Is passing the setState method to the Viewmodel class in some way dangerous?

Comment: Your code doesn't look like it would work. You aren't passing `notify` to `Viewmodel`, and `setProps({vm.value})` is invalid syntax.

Comment: @vr. apologies I have corrected some issues. I simplified this code from some larger code base I was using.